# Why does Firefox squeeze Windows' heart, but not Ubuntu's?

Tags: unicode, fonts, cross-browser, typography

I'm trying to display the heart ♥ Unicode character (U+2665 BLACK HEART SUIT) in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytzRf/2/).

Even though I've specified the `Droid Sans` font, the different browsers are displaying the same character differently. So, I'm assuming that the `Droid Sans` font doesn't include the ♥ character and the browser must fallback to some other font to display this character. But how does the browser determine which font to use for Unicode characters; as it turns out (from screenshots) that it's not operating system specific as Firefox and Chromium both on Ubuntu display it differently; and also it is not browser specific as Firefox displays it differently on Ubuntu and Windows 7.

So my questions are - **How does a browser determine which font to use to display Unicode characters; how can I find out which font is being used by the browser to display Unicode characters; and how can I ensure a consistent look cross-browser?**

**PS:** (Firefox specific) Even though `Droid Sans` doesn't include the ♥ character, Firefox displays it as in screenshot only when the selected font is `Droid Sans`. For any other font, Firefox picks up the `DejaVu Sans` font to display the ♥ character (on Ubuntu, confirmed by hit and trial).

[image]

Comment: Font mapping rules are convoluted and unpredictable since they depend on what fonts are installed on the user's machine.  The actual shape is determined by the font designer.  If you want to guarantee a particular shape then you'll need to use an image instead of a character.

Comment: @HansPassant What is guaranteed for the screenshots is that they are from the same machine, so same set of installed fonts.

Comment: "Same machine" with different operating systems doesn't count as "same".

Comment: @HansPassant Of course. By "same set of installed fonts", I meant same set of installed fonts per operating system (so technically two set of installed fonts in the attached screenshot). But I thought that was understood. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Droid Sans font does not contain U+2665 BLACK HEART SUIT, so declaring the font is rather irrelevant here. I cannot reproduce the observation in your “PS”, so I’m not trying to explain it.

(A quick way to check character coverage in a font is to download and install the [LastResort](http://www.unicode.org/policies/lastresortfont_eula.html) font. It contains a generic, easily recognizable rendering for all characters, so by using `font-family: foo, LastResort` on your test text you will quickly find out whether a particular character exists in font “foo”.)

The use of fallback fonts is browser-dependent. Browsers may have settings for this. But the point is that you, as an author, cannot know what happens on other people’s browsers, when your characters cannot be found in the list of fonts you specify (as installed, if installed, in the user’s computer).

Comment: I just want to know what is happening in my own browsers, on which I've supposedly complete control.